# [Ljava.lang.String; error when trying to split Array List in Java

Tags: java, csv, file, arraylist, split

I'm fairly new to java and I believe the problem comes from my lack of understanding.

I am trying to read an Array List of CSV values.  Below is my code:

```
    public static void readFile(){
        String line = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Main.filepath));

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){  //reads whilst the next line is not null
                fileData.add(line);                 //adds current line to array list
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("File Not Found");   //if file not found, print
        }
    }
```

```
public class Film{
    public static void duration(){
        readFile();
        for (int i = 0; i < (fileData.size()); i++) {
            //System.out.println(fileData);
            String[] temp = fileData.get(1).split(",");
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
```

`readFile()` reads the CSV file and saves each line as an element in an ArrayList

`filedata` is the ArrayList

`filepath` is the path to the file

The CSV file is in format `"filmName,releaseDate,filmRating,filmGenre,filmDuration,filmScore"`

I'm trying to get Film() to print out the release dates of every element in the ArrayList, however my output is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@6bf2d08e
[Ljava.lang.String;@5eb5c224
[Ljava.lang.String;@53e25b76
[Ljava.lang.String;@73a8dfcc
```

When I'm expecting something more like

```
1999
2007
1956
1987
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each `String` of the array `tmp` and print that value. Moreover, you  should replace `fileData.get(1).split(",");` for  `fileData.get(i).split(",");`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < (fileData.size()); i++) {
            String[] tmp = fileData.get(i).split(",");
            for(String t : tmp)
                System.out.println(tmp);
   }
```

If you  `System.out.println();` the array you will be printing basically, each String hashcode. Alternatively, you can use `Arrays.toString` to print the entire array in one go:

```
for (String fileDatum : fileData) {
    String[] tmp = fileDatum.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
}
```

Finally, you use Streams from Java you can simplify your method to only:

```
 fileData.stream().map(i -> i.split(",")).forEach(i -> Arrays.asList(i).forEach(System.out::println));
```

or with a different formatting style:

```
  fileData.stream().map(i -> i.split(",")).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] temp = fileData.get(1).split(",");
System.out.println(temp);
```

This prints out the Array with the default implementation of toString:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
> toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
> object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
> that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
> subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
> the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
> character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
> code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
> to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

In your case you need to iterate over the Array again and spring each element with toString

Answer (score 0):

You have to first reefer to i variable instead of 1 in your loop, then the split method returns an array of String, so you should select the correct value in the array :

```
 String[] temp = fileData.get(i).split(",");
 System.out.println(temp[1]);
```